# SQL - How to find out that a status field has no record with a value equal to 3

Tags: sql, select

I have a table that can look like this:

| user_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 |

table has user_id, and status column,
the status column is integer has 1,2,3,4,5 state, each user can has one than one record
but only can has one record that status is 3.

How to find out that a status field has no record with a value equal to 3

Please help!

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an aggregation approach:

```sql
SELECT user_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Using exists logic we can try:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND
          t2.status = 3
);
```